# Multiple classes against the same interfaces in Unity Container

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

i have an interface "IRunAtStartup" which is implemented across several classes. the interface has a method "Execute" which needs to be executed for all the classes on the application startup.

at the time of compilation, i am not aware the number of classes implementing the interface and hence this really needs to be written in a generic way.

Using Unity for the IOC and following are 2 approaches i have tried 2 approaches

1) throws runtime error:

```
container.RegisterTypes(runAtStartUp, WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces);
```

2) throws a compilation error - "cannot resolve type" in the register command inside for loop. i am relatively new to Unity world and suspect that i am missing some basic issue here.

```
IEnumerable<Type> runAtStartUp = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType<IRunAtStartup>(true);

foreach (var type in runAtStartUp)
{
    container.RegisterType<IRunAtStartup, type>(type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
}
foreach (var task in container.ResolveAll<IRunAtStartup>())
            {
                task.Execute();
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Approach 2 seems OK to me, there may be a problem with one of the types being registered.

Comment: approach 2 does not even compiles.  here is a screenshot of the same: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11374665/approach-2.JPG

Comment: Oh. You are using invalid C# syntax, missed that. Use `container.RegisterType(typeof(IRunAtStartup), type, type.AssemblyQualifiedName)` instead.

Comment: That works perfect... do you want to post this as the answer so that i can mark it as answer ? i knew i was missing something basic, just did not realize what it was...

Comment: I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the approach 2 is correct (use named registrations), however you have a C# syntax error. The method to use is:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRunAtStartup), type, type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

Comment: i have a slightly different scenario now but i suspect i am making again a syntactical mistake... can you spot something right away ?        **foreach (var settingClass in typeFinder.FindClassesOfType<ISettings>(true))
        {
            container.Resolve<ISettingService>().LoadSetting<typeof(settingClass)>("domId");
        }**

Comment: here is a link with screenshot. [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11374665/LoadSetting.JPG) appreciate your help, @cynic

Comment: You can create a non-generic version of the method on the right - that is, `LoadSettings(Type settingsType, string domainGuid...)`. Or you can use reflection to call the existing generic version. You simply can't call generic methods in C# the way you do - between the < > goes the type name, known at compile time, not the `System.Type` instance known at run time.

Comment: thanks for prompt response. however, ive seen something similar in an open source application which is using autofac, here is a screenshot of the same [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11374665/LoadSetting-similar.JPG)

Comment: Note that the `TSettings` in that case is a type parameter. You can "pass" a type parameter to another generic method if the generic constraints allow it (that is, you write `LoadSetting<TSettings>()` and it compiles). You can get a `System.Type` instance inside a generic method via `typeof(TSettings)`. What you cannot do is to call either `BuildRegistration<TSettings>` or `LoadSetting<TSettings>` with a `System.Type` instance.

Comment: thanks again. ive sorted it out now using the approach suggested by you.